# android org.apache.http.httpclient package

Tags: android, apache, http

I am trying to import the code from this tutorial http://www.anddev.org/bbc_download.php?p=777&item=7

into my eclipse,the tutorial is oldand I have trouble importing the packages that it refers.

Are those packages deprecated? or I have to manually download and install them into my projects classhpath? if so can someone give me a link on where to find them?

Answer (score 0):

I see just postMethod has changed

use ::

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
```

Comment: Hi Jorgesys, first I have posted a wrong URL the correct one is this:http://www.anddev.org/poor_mans_gps_-_celltowerid_-_location_area_code_-lookup-t257.html
also forgot to mention that I am using google api version 2.1
The import statements (org.apache.commons.httpclient.*) doesnt work for me.
thanks maxsap.

Comment: you have to use now org.apache.http.client.methods.*

Comment: I have imported rg.apache.http.client.methods.* with no luck, still the Http classes that are used in the example arent recognized.