# How to add timeout to an HTTP Post

Tags: android, http, timeout, android-internet

Why the code is Not working for me, Even the connection is stale, (there is no response from the server for a long time, the code is not throwing any exception!

```
try{

    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();  
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 3000);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);              
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("url");  
    post.setParams(httpParameters);
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ab ", cd));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));           
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);           
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new 

    InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));              
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
   {

   }
  }
   catch(java.net.SocketTimeoutException e4)
   {
      Toast.makeText(xyz.this, "Your connection is stale", 10000).show();
   }
   catch (IOException e2) 
   {
  Log.d("G22", "Entered Exception");    
   }
   catch (Exception e2) 
   {
      Toast.makeText(xyz.this, "Your connection is stale..", 10000).show();
      e2.printStackTrace();
      Log.d("G22", "Entered Exception");    
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use `HttpClient` and `HttpPost`?  You could use an `HttpURLConnection`, which has the [`setConnectTimeout(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29) method:

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4596713/512958) for an example of using `HttpsURLConnection` for a POST operation.

Comment: What is the correspondence code for ``List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ab", cd));`` It would be very helpful and highly appreciating if you could tailor out the code (as given in the link) and make it appropriate so it can be used here. As far as I have seen (during one quick run through your code), here is no need of any cookie consideration and many other stuff as given in that code.

Comment: The `output` string is just a set of name/value pairs, so you'd have something like: `String output = "ab="+cd+"&foo="+bar;`

Answer (score 0):

U can Use this code

```
    HttpTransportSE MyandroidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertWeight.asmx",50000);
    //50000 is the timeout for this connection
```